# Create CSV encoding incorrect?

Tags: php, csv, encoding, export-to-csv

I am using php to create CSV files to be able to import this information into an other program. For some reason the created csv files is not imported in this program but when I open this file first in Excel and save it I am able to import into this other program.

Maybe an encoding problem? Suggestions how to solve this?

**File export php**

[image]

.

**File save Excel**

[image]

```
<?php
for ($j = 0; $j <= $aantal_regels; $j++)
{
    $csv_output .= $klantnaam.';';
    $csv_output .= $klant_ref.';';
    $csv_output .= $posno[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= $aantal[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= $dikte[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= $kwaliteit[$j].';';
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file;

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$lang['lijst_dxf']." ".$dossier_nr." ".$klantnaam." ".$klant_ref.".csv");
?>
```

Comment: Replace `"\n"` with `PHP_EOL` which is the operating system dependant version of new line.

Comment: Also remove `.';'` from `$csv_output .= $kwaliteit[$j].';';`

Comment: Does not make any difference using `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Try hard coding it to "\r\n"